# Suppress Linker Warning "object file ... was built for newer OSX version than being linked

Tags: xcode, linker, clang, warnings, suppress-warnings

Is there a clang linker flag to suppress this particular warning? I am using a third party static library that won't compile under the deployment targets version. I am aware of the importance of this warning and systems older than the version of the third party library won't use it in the app.

Adjusting the deployment target version is not an option at the moment. Still I'd like to get other possible linker warnings, so "-w" is not good, either.

Thanks in advance!